Relation between Brownian motion and Weierstrass function
I was reading on Brownian motion and it's properties from Øksendal's book, he mentioned it's continuous yet nowhere differentiable. I remembered a famous example that's also continous and nowhere differentiable, the Weierstrass function;
$$W(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n \cos(b^n \pi x)$$
Now, I know Brownian motion has quadratic variation, and I'm trying to figure out the variance of Weierstrass function to see if there is a relation. What is it's variance and is there a relation between the two?

I think your focus on the Weierstrass function is misguided. For each continuous function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and for each $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists continuum many (i.e. $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$ many) nowhere differentiable continuous functions $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb R.$ For instance, no matter what continuous function you choose, there are uncountably many nowhere differentiable continuous functions whose graphs stay within a ${10}^{-1000}$-width tube about that continuous function's graph.

Also, I'm fairly certain that the same result holds if we additionally assume that the functions $g$ all have quadratic variance, and if we additionally assume that all the functions $g$ do NOT have quadratic variance (two different strengthenings of the result). My point is why focus on the Weierstrass function? This is like looking at a set containing a lot of irrational numbers (uncountably many in every interval; these are like your Brownian motion functions) then "randomly" singling out some irrational number and asking if there is a connection between that set and the irrational number.

Related is this more focused mathoverflow question: Weierstrass' function and Brownian motion. See also Section 4.2: Quadratic Variation for the Weierstrass Function (pp. 56-62) of David Nielsen Horton's 2018 Ph.D. dissertation Analysis of Weierstrass Function and its effect on Loewner Hulls.

I think the term is "quadratic variation" rather than "quadratic variance".
